# How to display my datatable as a matrix?

Tags: c#, datatable, multidimensional-array, matrix, console-application

How do I get my datatable to get the following format:

```
             England   Germany   Holland   Spain   Germany   Russia   Japan

England         x

Germany                    x

Holland                             x

Spain                                         x

Germany                                               x

Russia                                                          x

Japan                                                                    x
```

I did get some answers before, but that was with another way. I actually want my datatable to be used in this. Also it would be nice if you could help me out on how to display the input on the correct coordinates.

best regards

**My table**

```
    DataTable Matrix = new DataTable();
        Matrix.TableName = "Matrix";
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Ado"));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Ajax", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AZ", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FC-GR", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FC-TW", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FC-U", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Fey", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Her", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Nac", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PSV", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RKC", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ROD", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SC", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Spa", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Vit", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VVV", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("WIL", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));




        Matrix.Rows.Add("Ado Den Haag", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("Ajax", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("AZ", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("FC Groningen", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("FC Twente", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("FC Utrecht", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("Feyenoord", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("Hercules Almelo", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("NAC Breda", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("PSV", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("RKC Waalwijk", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("Roda JC", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("SC Heerenveen", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("Sparta Rotterdam", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("Vitesse", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("VVV-Venlo", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        Matrix.Rows.Add("Willem II", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
```

Comment: Does it need to be in a console application? Doing this in Winforms or WPF is so much easier and clearer.

Comment: yes it has to be - i know it will be a lot easier in WPF - I just WISH i could have done it in WPF - but I am not allowed. So I really need some help here

Comment: Litarely nobody knows - even on msdn it's always about windows forms. I just dont know how to ever finish this project =/

Comment: do you want print this schema in console? put  all data in matrix and print it wite console.writeline

Comment: @DeveloperX: The problem is that it should look as a matrix, therefore placement of the 'x'-s have to be correct.

Comment: Also there needs to be input in this - which makes it hard to put it in console.Writeline and then get user input on the correct coords

Comment: Well I think pseudo code should look like table.column.add("Name"); table.column.add("England");table.column.add("Germany"); and so on. and then table.row.add("England"); table.row.add("Germany"); and so on.

Comment: yes i have the table columns and rows, but eventually i need to print it like this - and then put user input in the right coords

Comment: So you can name countries in bottom line 1 England, 2 Germany... and in rows A England, B Germany. Then ask user to enter number and letter that represents coordinates of your matrix.

Comment: How do I read the input as coords?

Comment: Can you show us the Structure of table contains data

Comment: You could use [Console.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) method and do something like this: Console.WriteLine("Enter country number:"); string xCoordinate = Console.ReadLine(); Console.WriteLine("Enter country letter:"); string yCoordinate = Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @reniuz I dont think its finished there, its still not displaying it on the right place, It picks the right row - but the wrong column.

Comment: so you doing something wrong :) if user enters 1 column so you need to take column[1] if user enters 1(or A) for row you need to take row[0].

Comment: in the end it will be like clubs[myCol, myRow] = answer;  Thats the same thing as you trying to do - myCol would be for example 1 and then my row would be 6, then you will have the coords 1,6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a project was printing on dot matrix Printers ,i changed my code it can help you for displaying create an console project and replace the code with mine

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
namespace Matrix
{
    class Program
    {
        public static System.Data.DataTable CreateTeamTable()
        {
            DataTable team = new DataTable();
            team.TableName = "Team";

            team.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TeamCode", typeof(int)));
            team.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TeamName", typeof(string)));

            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, "Ado Den Haag" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "AZ" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "FC Groningen" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "FC Twente" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "FC Utrecht" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Feyenoord" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "Hercules Almelo" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, "NAC Breda" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, "PSV" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, "Roda JC" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, "SC Heerenveen" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, "Sparta Rotterdam" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, "Vitesse" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, "VVV-Venlo" });
            team.Rows.Add(new object[] { 14, "Willem II" });
            return team;
        }
        public static System.Data.DataTable CreateMatchTable()
        {
            DataTable matchTable = new DataTable();
            matchTable.TableName = "Match";
            matchTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Host", typeof(int)));
            matchTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Guest", typeof(int)));
            matchTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(string)));
            matchTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("HostScor", typeof(int)));
            matchTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GuestScor", typeof(int)));

            return matchTable;
        }
        public static List<MatrixItem> ToMatrix(System.Data.DataTable tbl)
        {
            var result = new List<MatrixItem>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in tbl.Columns)
            {

                int j = 0;
                int x = 0;
                foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in tbl.Rows)
                {

                    var col = item[column].ToString();
                    if (i > 0)
                        col = string.Empty;
                    if (x == 0)
                    {
                        col = column.ColumnName;
                    }
                    if ((j == i) && (i > 0))
                        col = "*";
                    var m = new MatrixItem() { ColData = col, X = x, Y = i };
                    x += 15;
                    result.Add(m);
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return result;
        }
        public static List<MatrixItem> CreateSample()
        {
            var list = new List<MatrixItem>();

            var countries = new string[] { "          ", "England   ", "Germany   ", "Holland   ", "Spain   ", "Germany   ", "Russia   ", "Japan" };
            for (int i = 0; i < countries.Length; i++)
            {
                int x = 0;
                int j = 0;
                foreach (var item in countries)
                {
                    var col = item;
                    if (i > 0)
                        col = string.Empty;
                    if (x == 0)
                    {
                        col = countries[i];
                    }
                    if ((j == i) && (i > 0))
                        col = "*";
                    var m = new MatrixItem() { ColData = col, X = x, Y = i };
                    x += item.Length;
                    list.Add(m);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
        public static void PrintMenu(System.Data.DataTable tblTeam)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in tblTeam.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} )- {1}", item["TeamCode"], item["TeamName"]));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to Enter Results");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2 to show result table");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Command Number");
        }
        public static void printMatrix(List<MatrixItem> list)
        {
            var j = 0;
            DosPrinter ds = new DosPrinter(900, 18);
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                ds.PrintXY(item.X, item.Y, item.ColData);
            }
            ds.Finilize();
        }
        public static int Readint()
        {
            string gcstr = Console.ReadLine();
            int gc = 0;
            while (!Int32.TryParse(gcstr, out gc))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bad Value ( press x to exit app) re enter code : ");
                gcstr = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (gcstr.ToLower() == "x")
                return -1;
            return gc;
        }
        public static void GetResults(System.Data.DataTable results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Guest Code: ");
            int hc = Readint();
            Console.Write("Enter HostCode Code: ");
            int gc = Readint();
            Console.Write("Enter Match date: ");
            string dateStr = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter host score: ");
            int hs = Readint();
            Console.Write("Enter Guestscore: ");
            int gs = Readint();
            results.Rows.Add(new object[] { hc, gc, dateStr, hs, gs });
        }
        public static void ShowResult(System.Data.DataTable tblTeam,System.Data.DataTable tblMatches)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            var matrixList = new List<MatrixItem>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow horzRow in tblTeam.Rows)
            {
                int x = 0;
                int j = 0;
                foreach (System.Data.DataRow vertRow in tblTeam.Rows)
                {
                    string col = string.Empty;
                    if (i > 0 & j > 0)
                    {
                        var rs = tblMatches.Select(string.Format("(Host={0} and guest={1}) or (Host={1} and guest={0})", horzRow["TeamCode"], vertRow["TeamCode"]));
                        if (rs.Length > 0)
                            col = "*";
                    }
                    if (i == 0 & j == 0)
                    {
                        col = "        ";
                    }
                    if ((i == 0) && (j > 0))
                    {
                        col = vertRow["TeamName"].ToString();
                    }
                    if ((i > 0) && (j == 0))
                    {
                        col = horzRow["TeamName"].ToString();
                    }

                    var m = new MatrixItem() { ColData = col, X = x, Y = i };
                    x += 25;
                    matrixList.Add(m);
                    j++;

                }
                i++;
            }
            printMatrix( matrixList );
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var teams = CreateTeamTable();
            var matches = CreateMatchTable();
            int x = 'a';
            while (x != 'x')
            {
                PrintMenu(teams);

                x = Console.Read();
                if (x == '1')
                {
                    GetResults(matches);
                }
                if (x == '2')
                {
                    ShowResult(teams, matches);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class MatrixItem
    {
        public string ColData { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

    }
    public class DosPrinter
    {
        #region Fields
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private byte[,] canvas;
        private int baseX = 0;
        private int baseY = 0;


        #endregion



        #region Functionality


        public void PrintXY(int x, int y, string value)
        {
            int startx = baseX + x;// -value.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                canvas[startx + i, baseY + y] = Convert.ToByte(value[i]);
            }
        }
        public void Finilize()
        {
            object k = 1;
            object l = 0;
            object lf = false;
            object ss = " ";

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                {

                    Array crt = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), baseX + this.width);
                    string line = string.Empty;
                    for (int j = 0; j < baseX + width; j++)
                    {
                        crt.SetValue(canvas[j, i], j);
                        line += ((char)canvas[j, i]).ToString();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    //vbPrinter.PrintBytes(ref crt, ref LineFeed);
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        public void CleareBuffer()
        {
            InitCanvas();
        }
        public void InitCanvas()
        {
            canvas = new byte[baseX + width, baseY + height];
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                    canvas[i, j] = 32;
                }
            }
        }
        public string DrawLine(int len)
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                line += "-";
            }
            return line;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public DosPrinter(int width, int height)
        {
            this.width = baseX + width;
            this.height = baseY + height;
            InitCanvas();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that looks pretty good. But how do I read input into this ?

Comment: did you test my code,now you want to create List<matrix> from your table,its so simple think more;)

Comment: Ye i tested it, But I was busy for so long on my own - hammering with the same thing over and over - now that i got a new code, it kinda overwhelmed me with new variables :P

Comment: the basic idea is i have a rectangle surface that has cells in,each cell is a character,when i cal printxy function i put each character ofinput value in correct position in this surface and finally i print all caharacter in console

Comment: do u want to shae all season games in a table? if its your goal ,i think you should change the table

Comment: I am kinda ashamed to say - but I have never used those functions in my life - I have no clue how to add user input into that datatable

Comment: Yes i do want to see all seasons games - The user just puts in his answers. He should be filling the date or the score of the match.

Comment: so,i edit my answer to create tables :),you know i will go to play football 3 hour later so i have some free time;)

Comment: Cool I appreciate that and looking forward to your solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'am a bit late with my example, but still I spent some time to do it so I post it :)
Example code prints table and asks to enter column number, row number and value after that prints table again to show result. Keep in mind that its example how to print matrix and edit its value.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable Matrix = new DataTable();
        Matrix.TableName = "Matrix";
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(MakeStringBeutiful("Name")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(MakeStringBeutiful("1 England")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(MakeStringBeutiful("2 Germany")));
        Matrix.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(MakeStringBeutiful("3 France ")));


        Matrix.Rows.Add("1 England", "    x    ", "         ", "         ");
        Matrix.Rows.Add("2 Germany", "         ", "    x    ", "         ");
        Matrix.Rows.Add("3 France ", "         ", "         ", "    x    ");

        PrintMatrix(Matrix);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter column number:");
        string sx = Console.ReadLine();
        int x = int.Parse(sx);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter row number:");
        string sy = Console.ReadLine();
        int y = int.Parse(sy);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter value:");
        string v = Console.ReadLine();

        SetValue(x, y, v, Matrix);
        PrintMatrix(Matrix);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void SetValue(int x, int y, string value, DataTable table)
    {
        table.Rows[y - 1][x]=MakeStringBeutiful(value);
    }

    private static void PrintMatrix(DataTable m)
    {
        string s = "|";
        foreach (DataColumn item in m.Columns)
        {
            s += item.ColumnName+"|";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        string j = "|";
        foreach (DataRow item in m.Rows)
        {
            foreach (object ob in item.ItemArray)
            {
                j += ob.ToString()+"|";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(j);
            j = "|";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
    }

    private static string MakeStringBeutiful(string str)
    {
        while (str.Length < 9)
            str += " ";
        return str;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey untill that far i did get it. You have the exact same thing as I do. As soon as you fill the answer the output will only pick the row and won't stand beneath the right column